# Failing to get PyCharm to work with remote interpreter on docker

Tags: docker, pycharm, docker-compose

When I add a remote interpreter from one of my `docker-compose`, it doesn't seem to succeed and doesn't show any packages in the dialog. When I add an interpreter to the debugger it says:

```
python packaging tools not found.
```

Then if i click on install packaging tools, error displayed:

```
ERROR: for dockeryard_pycharm_helpers_1
Cannot start service pycharm_helpers: network not found

Starting dockeryard_postgres_1 ...  
Starting dockeryard_nginx_1    ...  
Starting dockeryard_redis_1    ... 
Starting dockeryard_postgres_1 ... 
Starting dockeryard_nginx_1 ...  
Starting dockeryard_pycharm_helpers_1  
Starting dockeryard_redis_1  
Starting dockeryard_worker_1 ... 
Starting dockeryard_worker_1
Starting dockeryard_pycharm_helpers_1
ERROR: for dockeryard_pycharm_helpers_1  Cannot start service     pycharm_helpers: network not found

ERROR: for pycharm_helpers  Cannot start service pycharm_helpers: network not found
[31m  
ERROR [0m:
```

Note, this interpreter was already in use and I was able to connect remotely with PyCharm, but I have added and eventually removed a custom network to the container.

As explained in [Configuring Remote Python Interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html) - "When a remote Python interpreter is added, at first the PyCharm helpers are copied to the remote host". And my guess something went wrong since network was updated in the docker-compose.

From what I understand from the error message, when PyCharm starts interpreter it tries to use/find that network      `c7b0cc277c94ba5f58f6e72dcbab1ba24794e72422e839a83ea6102d08c40452`.

I don't see that network listed anywhere when I run:

```
$ docker network inspect dockeryard_default
```

So PyCharm stores it somewhere and not been updated with the change.
I have tried to remove interpreter (using PyCharm dialog) and add it back - same result.

How can I get rid of this network and make PyCharm to be able to debug again?

Thanks.

Comment: None of these answer solve this issue in Pycharm 2022 PY-222.4345.23. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Was having a near identical error and was able to get past it. I did two things though I'm uncertain as to which was the actual solution:

1. Made sure the mappings were correct under both (a) `Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Path mappings` and (b) `Run -> Edit Configurations -> <Your_Configuration> -> Path mappings`
2. Removed/deleted any containers that looked to be related to PyCharm (believe this is more than likely what solved things).

Hope this helps. PyCharm `docker-compose` seems to work for some and be a real PITA for others.

One other note. I downgraded from PyCharm 2018 to 2017.3 as there's known docker bugs in 2018.

EDIT: And it would seem a `docker-compose down` from CLI reintroduces the error -_-

Comment: I did the second of these things and it fixed my problem.

`docker ps -a | grep -i pycharm | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm`

Comment: Remove the container named 'pycharm_helpers' is work for me.

Comment: Using docker-compose v2 instead of v3 for docker-compose interpreter is much more stable for me.

Comment: To get this to work, I deleted all my containers and images.

Comment: @peterc needs to post his comment as the answer, that was the solution for me.

Answer (score 32):

## TLDR:

The `{project_name}_pycharm_helpers_{pycharm_build_number}` volume has been removed or is corrupted.

To repopulate it, run:

```
docker volume rm {project_name}_pycharm_helpers_{pycharm_build_number}
docker run -v {project_name}_pycharm_helpers_{pycharm_build_number}:/opt/.pycharm_helpers pycharm_helpers:{pycharm_build_number}
```

The pycharm_build_number can be found in the about section of your pycharm (mac OS: Pycharm > About)

## Long story

I struggled *a lot* with PyCharm suddenly not finding the helpers any more or any related bugs, sometimes because I was clearing my containers or volumes. For instance, running

```
docker rm -f `docker container ps -aq`
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

will almost surely get pycharm into troubles.

AFAIK about how PyCharm works, there is:

- a PyCharm base image named `pycharm_helpers` with tag corresponding to your pycharm build number (for example: PY-202.7660.27)
- the first time you create docker related things, PyCharm creates `volumes` that get data from this image for later use in your containers. For instance, after a first attempt at running a remote docker-compose interpreter, I see the newly created `myproject_pycharm_helpers_PY-202.7660.27` volume when doing `docker volume ls`.
- when running the docker interpreter, PyCharm adds this volume into the `/opt/.pycharm_helpers` directory by adding at some point a `-v myproject_pycharm_helpers_PY-202.7660.27:/opt/.pycharm_helpers` to your command. For instance using docker-compose, you can see the addition of the `-f /Users/clementwalter/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.2/tmp/docker-compose.override.1508.yml` and when you actually look into this file you see:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  local:
    command:
    - "python"
    - "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py"
    - "--mode=server"
    - "--port=55824"
    entrypoint: ""
    environment:
      PYCHARM_MATPLOTLIB_INTERACTIVE: "true"
      PYTHONPATH: "/opt/project:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/third_party/thriftpy:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev"
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
      PYTHONIOENCODING: "UTF-8"
      PYCHARM_MATPLOTLIB_INDEX: "0"
      PYCHARM_HOSTED: "1"
      PYCHARM_DISPLAY_PORT: "63342"
      IPYTHONENABLE: "True"
    volumes:
    - "/Users/clementwalter/Documents/myproject:/opt/project:rw"
    - "pycharm_helpers_PY-202.7660.27:/opt/.pycharm_helpers"
    working_dir: "/opt/project"
volumes:
  pycharm_helpers_PY-202.7660.27: {}
```

You get into troubles when this volume is not correctly populated anymore.
Fortunately the [docker volume documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) has a section "Populate a volume using a container" which is exactly what PyCharm does under the hood.

For the record you can check the content of the pycharm_helpers image:

```
$ docker run -it pycharm_helpers:PY-202.7660.27 sh
/opt/.pycharm_helpers #
```

you end up into the pycharm_helpers directory and find all the helpers here:

```
/opt/.pycharm_helpers # ls -la
total 5568
drwxr-xr-x   21 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Dec 17 11:07 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           274 Dec 17 11:07 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 MathJax
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2526 Sep 16 11:14 check_all_test_suite.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3194 Sep 16 11:14 conda_packaging_tool.py
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 coverage_runner
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 coveragepy
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         11586 Sep 16 11:14 docstring_formatter.py
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 epydoc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           519 Sep 16 11:14 extra_syspath.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 generator3
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             8 Sep 16 11:14 icon-robots.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3950 Sep 16 11:14 packaging_tool.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       1490666 Sep 16 11:14 pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 pockets
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 profiler
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           863 Sep 16 11:14 py2ipnb_converter.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 py2only
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 py3only
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 pycharm
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 pycharm_display
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 pycharm_matplotlib_backend
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        103414 Sep 16 11:14 pycodestyle.py
drwxr-xr-x   24 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 pydev
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 python-skeletons
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 rest_runners
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        583493 Sep 16 11:14 setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         29664 Sep 16 11:14 six.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 sphinxcontrib
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           128 Sep 16 11:14 syspath.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 third_party
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 tools
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Dec 17 16:38 typeshed
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       3354133 Sep 16 11:14 virtualenv-16.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

- to make these helpers available again, following the docker documentation, you have to fix the volume. To do so:

```
docker rm {project_name}_pycharm_helpers_{pycharm_build}
docker run -v {project_name}_pycharm_helpers_{pycharm_build}:"/opt/.pycharm_helpers" pycharm_helpers:{tag}
```

et voilà

Comment: I found that `invalidate cache and restart` also repopulated the volumes.

Comment: @21rw is correct. Run `docker volume prune`, delete all pycharm related container, then invalidate caches (tick the options clear VCS logs and clear downloaded shared index) works for me.

Comment: Had this issue after purging my whole Docker system (volumes as well), this helped, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

If you're still seeing this in PyCharm `2020.2` then do this:

- close PyCharm
- try @peterc's suggestion:

```
docker ps -a | grep -i pycharm | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm
```

- launch PyCharm again

Comment: Worked for me still in Jan 2022, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The option `invalidate cache` -> `Clear downloaded shared indexes` will also repopulate the Pycharm volumes. (At least in 2021.1)

Answer (score 0):

As of PyCharm 2023.3.3, the volume is no longer named in accordance with the image name, and just has a randomly assigned identifier.

I found this issue manifested when using Podman as a drop-in replacement for Docker. The volume was initially empty, starting and stopping the container would populate the volume

```
$ podman container ls -a
podman container ls -a
CONTAINER ID  ...  NAMES
312553e157d1  ...  pycharm_helpers_PY-233.13763.11
```

then

```
$ podman container start pycharm_helpers_PY-233.13763.11
$ podman container stop pycharm_helpers_PY-233.13763.11
```

After that the volume would be populated and debugging worked as expected.